# Add 'rules' to a calendar event in Outlook?

Tags: outlook.com-calendar

I have this idea that I want a block of time set for doing something random on a Saturday. I can't think of a way I can put this in my Outlook calendar apart from creating a script that picks a random item from a list of possible activities that I might want to do on a Saturday, then create an event based on that item.

Is there anything that already exists for this?